# Ajax code not working with codeigniter, PHP.?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here I am trying to login with Ajax and Codeigniter, but can't get success.
Here is My little code which is not working with ajax but working with form action.

This is controller code

```
<?php

    class loginmodal extends CI_Controller{


        function login(){   
            $data['title'] = 'USER AUTHENTICATION';
            $this->load->view("loginmodal", $data);

        }
        function index(){
            echo'<script type="text/javascript> alert("php 0"); </script>"';    
        }
        function login_validation(){

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('login_username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('login_password', 'Password', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');

            if($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                    //true
                    $Uname = $this->input->post('login_username');
                    $Pass  =  $this->input->post('login_password');
                    $url =  $this->input->post('current_loginurl');

                    // model function_exists
                    $this->load->model('include/main_loginmodal');                  
                    if($this->main_loginmodal->can_login($Uname, $Pass))
                    {
                        $session_data = array (
                                'username' => $Uname
                        );
                        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
                        //redirect(base_url(). 'article');
                        //$this->session->set_flashdata('redirectToCurrent', base_url());
                        //redirect($this->session->flashdata('redirectToCurrent'));
                        //redirect(base_url()/current_url(), 'refresh');

                        redirect(base_url(). 'loginmodal/enter');

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
                        ;
                        redirect(base_url(). 'article');
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                //false;
                $this->login(); 
                //exit

            }
        }

        function  enter()
        {
            if($this->session->userdata('username') != '')
            {
                redirect(base_url(). 'loginmodal/index');
                //redirect($url);
                echo 'Login Success'.$this->session->userdata('username');
                echo'<script type="text/javascript> alert("php 1"]); </script>"';
            }
            else
            {
                redirect(base_url(). 'loginmodal/article');
                echo'<script type="text/javascript> alert("php 2"]); </script>"';
            }
        }

        function logout()
        {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
            redirect(base_url(). 'loginmodal/index');
        }
    }

?>
```

This is my ajax code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#loginform").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); 

            $.ajax({

                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>include/loginmodal/login_validation",  
                    type: "POST",
                    data: 
                    {
                        login_username: $('#login_username').val(),
                        login_password: $('#login_password').val()},

                        success: function(data) 
                        {
                            alert(data);
                            if (data !== '')
                            {   
                                alert("you are logged IN");
                                //window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1/simple_login_redirect/index.php/user/home");
                                //window.location.href="http://127.0.0.1/simple_login_comp/index.php/user/members";
                            }
                            else if(data === ''){

                                alert("sorry");
                            }

                        }

                });
                alert('data is ');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**This is my view code**

```
<!-- -Login Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content login-modal" style="background-color:#fff;">
                <div class="modal-header login-modal-header" >
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="loginModalLabel">USER AUTHANTICATION</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="login-tab">
                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                        <ul class="tab">
                                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'home')" id="defaultOpen">SignIn</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'profile')">SignUp</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'forget_password')">Forgot Password</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                            <!-- Tab panes -->

                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active text-center tabcontent " id="home" style="border:none; vertical-align:middle;" >
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <span id="login_fail" class="response_error" style="display: block;"><?php $this->session->flashdata("error");?></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <form method="post" action="" id = "loginform">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group" style="display : none;">
                                                 <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="current_loginurl" name="current_loginurl" placeholder="Username" style="background-color:#fff; color:#000;"
                                                        value="<?php echo current_url(); ?>">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" id="email-error"></span>
                                            <?php echo form_error('login_username'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_username" name="login_username" placeholder="Username" style="background-color:#fff; color:#000;">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" id="email-error"></span>
                                            <?php echo form_error('login_username'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login_password" name="login_password" placeholder="Password" style="background-color:#fff; color:#000;">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" id="password-error"><?php echo form_error('login_password'); ?></span>
                                        </div>

                                            <input type="checkbox" style="float: left; padding-top:10px;">&nbsp;&nbsp; RememberMe</input>
                                            <input type="submit" id="login_btn" class="btn btn-login" data-loading-text="Signing In...." style="float: right;" value="Login">
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" id="password-error"><?php echo form_error('login_password'); ?></span>

                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="login-modal-footer">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <!--<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>                                                  
                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="forgetpass-tab" style="padding-left: 48px;"> Forgot password? </a>                                                
                                                </div>                                              
                                                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="profile"> Sign Up </a>
                                                </div>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane tabcontent" id="profile">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <span id="registration_fail" class="response_error" style="display: none;">Registration failed, please try again.</span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <form method="post" action="">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="F_Name" placeholder="First Name"  style="background-color:#fff; color:#000;">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" data-error='0' id="username-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="L_Name" placeholder="Last Name"  style="background-color:#fff; color:#000;">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" data-error='0' id="remail-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                                                <input type="Email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email"  style="background-color:#fff; color:#000;">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" data-error='0' id="remail-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="r_password" placeholder="Password"  style="background-color:#fff; color:#000;">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" data-error='0' id="remail-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="rc_password" placeholder="Confirm Password"  style="background-color:#fff; color:#000;">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" data-error='0' id="remail-error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="button" id="register_btn" class="btn btn-block bt-login" data-loading-text="Registering....">Register</button>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="login-modal-footer">
                                            <!--<div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="forgetpass-tab"style="padding-left: 48px;"> Forgot password? </a>

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="signin-tab"> Sign In </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>-->
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane text-center tabcontent" id="forget_password">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <span id="reset_fail" class="response_error" style="display: none;"></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <form method="post" action="">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="femail" placeholder="Email"  style="background-color:#fff; color:#000;">
                                            </div>
                                            <span class="help-block has-error" data-error='0' id="femail-error"></span>
                                        </div>

                                        <button type="button" id="reset_btn" class="btn btn-block bt-login" style="padding-left: 48px;"data-loading-text="Please wait....">Forget Password</button>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="login-modal-footer">
                                            <!--<div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="signin-tab" style="padding-left: 48px;"> Sign In </a>

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="signup-tab"> Sign Up </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>-->
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**Model code is here**

```
<?php

    class main_loginmodal extends CI_Model{

        function can_login($Uname, $pass)
        {
            $this->db->where('Uname', $Uname);
            $this->db->where('Pass', $pass);

            $query = $this->db->get('datab');

            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

I am getting this erro in console. 404 Not found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TBbn.png)

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: where is the loginmodal/login_validation code for your ajax login?

Comment: it is here `controllers/include/loginmodal.php`

Comment: are you willing to share the content of that file with us?

Comment: I already put it here. First code of controller is `controllers/include/loginmodal.php`

Comment: you can't redirect in a ajax php function, you should create a different function that will return a status successfully logged or not

Comment: can You post example code.? for this

Answer (score 0):

Your $.ajax structure is wrong. Have added example ajax structure here, Please change your code structure as below.

```
          $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>include/loginmodal/login_validation", 
            method: 'POST',
            data: 'login_username='+$('#login_username').val()+'+&login_password='+$('#login_password').val(),
            success: function(data){
                // Success Code
            },
            error: function(e) {
                    //called when there is an error
                    console.table(e);
            }
          });
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong with his ajax? seems ok to me

Comment: I cant get any success message.? It just send only login failed message.

Comment: your `method` key is wrong it should be `type: 'POST'` and your URL make sure that your ajax included in your `.php` file otherwise it will make an error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **url** in your ajax request is correct. 404 means that the url is not found. In your screenshot full url is:

http://localhost:8080/data/application/controllers/include/loginmodal/login_validation

Make sure your base_url is properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

your ajax structure:

```
 $.ajax({
  url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/getclassid",
  dataType: "html",
  type: 'GET',
  data:'classid='+classid,               
   success: function(result) {
   $('#sec').html(result);  
  }
});
```

your controller code:

```
   public function getclassdivisionsbyclassid(){
   $classid = $_GET['classid'];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

with ajax call you can only redirect user based on the response you getting from your call. Have a look at my example.

// Ajax Script

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: your_url,
            data: your_form_data,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            beforeSend: function () {
                // do some animation loading: optional
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.data == TRUE)
                {
                  alert("LogedIN");
                  // redirect user to login page
                }
                else
                {
                   alert('Not Logedin');
                }
            },
            complete: function () {
                // stop loading animation: optional
            }
        });
```

// PHP Script
// return json

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {

        $response = array(
            'status' => 'OK',
            'data' => your can_login() method results
        );
        $this->output
                ->set_status_header(200)
                ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
                ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))
                ->_display();
        exit();
    }
```

Your model looks Ok, hope it works